# Replacing text in a Shell Script

Tags: command-line, sed, text, text-processing

I am running the command

```
echo 'link_1234' | sed 's|_|&/|g'
```

And it is returns the value of `link_/1234`

I need the `_` to be deleted

Is there any way to have the `_` be cleared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
echo 'link_1234' | sed 's|_||'
```

---

When you do:

```
echo 'link_1234' | sed 's|_|&/|g'
```

you are replacing `_` with `_/`. `sed` keeps the searched pattern as `&` so that you an use it in replacement as a shorthand, as your searched pattern is `_` and replacement is `&/`, you are replacing `_` with `_/`.

About the `g` modifier at the end, it is useful when there are more than one match and you want to do the replacement on all of them, as there is only one `_` so `g` is redundant here.